# How can I show three columns per row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been trying to show three columns per row. Is it possible using flexbox?

My current CSS is something like this:

```
.mainDiv {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 221px;
    margin-top: 43px;
}
```

This code puts all content in a single row.
I want to add a constraint to just shows three records per row.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/L4L67/

```css
body>div {
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

body>div>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
}

body>div>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #23a;
}

body>div>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #49b;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your markup is confusing. This works but considering making your example easier to understand/read.

Comment: This will show one or two columns when there's only one or two `div`s in side, due to `flex-grow`.

Comment: Remove `flex-grow` if you don't want the child elements to stretch out to fill the space.

Comment: @Barun, What if there are odd number of divs say 5? The second row will have 2 divs stretched full width and not that pretty looking. How to make the divs in 2nd row to take width same as that in 1st row?

Comment: @lifetimeLearner007 add `max-width: 33%;` and the odd divs will not fill the whole row

Comment: What if we want to have margin in between the columns?
Considering css column-gap property is still not widely supported for flex elements.

Answer (score 82):

Even though the above answer appears to be correct, I wanted to add a (hopefully) more readable example that also stays in 3 columns form at different widths:

```css
.flex-row-container {
    background: #aaa;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.flex-row-container > .flex-row-item {
    flex: 1 1 30%; /*grow | shrink | basis */
    height: 100px;
}

.flex-row-item {
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  border: 1px solid #f76707;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row-container">
  <div class="flex-row-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-row-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-row-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-row-item">4</div>
  <div class="flex-row-item">5</div>
  <div class="flex-row-item">6</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: thank for your answer. Please see my image below, how to make box 4,5 same with 1,2,3 ? image: https://prnt.sc/n29bm7

Comment: Hey @huykon225. Essentially you'd want to adjust your value for flex: 1 1 30%; on the flex-items. The "flex" property is a shorthand for 3 flex box properties: "[flex-grow] [flex-shrink] [flex-basis]" which define the widths and space filling properties of flex elements. Flex-basis sets the initial width of flex-items, and flex-grow describes how those items fill remaining space (based on the different flex-grow values). So in this case, you’d want to set a flex-basis value for the items that corresponds to the width you want (maybe 20%), and the flex-grow to “0”.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is a better approach to flexbox using the flex-wrap property.

Comment: Nice answer.
It demonstrates `flex-wrap: wrap;`.
Also, experimenting with the Stack Snippet shows how the `grow` property works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

Try this one using Grid Layout:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work a lot better than flex wrap + space-between when the number of items is variable, e.g there may be 2 items, or an odd number of items, like 5. If you want the items to have a fixed size, then space-between ruins the display by separating the 4th and 5th children, unlike with this solution

Answer (score 11):

You can now use [grid-auto-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow)

https://jsfiddle.net/chalcrow/bqye79kr/1/

**CSS**

```
.grid-flow {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

Note - the `repeat(3, 1fr)` means '3 columns, each taking up 1 (equal) fraction of the available space.

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-flow">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of a library that you may already have installed, bootstrap, and use [their grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints) which uses flexbox under the hood, while giving an easy to use semantic class naming system to implement it:

```
<!-- containers can have one or many child grids. Each grid should have a child row, which hold child columns -->
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>col</div>
    <div class='col'>col</div>
    <div class='col'>col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]