# Items in flex container not getting margins/justified evenly in container

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

Making simple React application with inputs. I do not understand why inputs, button and icon in flex container do not get margins nor they can not be justified evenly. I am using Material UI textfield and button components.

My code is like this:

```
 <div className="InputContainer">
        <form onSubmit={(event) => handleAddPerson(event)}>
            <TextField
                className="input"
                id="name"
                required
                label="Name"
                variant="filled"
                value={name}
                onChange={handleNameChange} />
            <TextField
                className="input"
                id="email"
                required
                label="E-mail address"
                variant="filled"
                value={email}
                onChange={handleEmailChange} />
            <TextField
                className="input"
                id="phone"
                required
                label="Phone number"
                variant="filled"
                value={phone}
                onChange={handlePhoneChange} />
            <Button
                className="addButton"
                variant="outlined"
                type="submit"

            >Add
            </Button>
            <CustomizedTooltip className="tooltip" title={tooltipText}>
                <IconButton><HelpOutlineIcon /></IconButton>
            </CustomizedTooltip>
        </form>
    </div>
```

CSS is here:

```
.InputContainer {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 72px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  width: 878px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.input {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 40px;
  /* margin-left: 20px; */
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.addButton {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 38px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}
```

I have tried things mentioned here: [Columns of text not aligning evenly in flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58503840/columns-of-text-not-aligning-evenly-in-flex-container) and here: [Better way to set distance between flexbox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626685/better-way-to-set-distance-between-flexbox-items). No luck. Should be easy to implement, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is what I am getting with this code: no space in between inputs and a button.[image]

Comment: Your button and icon should use `inline-block` as `display` property. Then add the margin you required.

Comment: Does not work. Still not getting margins. Damn.

Comment: Try use `gap` rule for parent selector in css.

Comment: Tried that earlier, and now tested:

 display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  column-gap: 16px;

Still no space in between.

Comment: `justify-content: 'space-evenly';` should be `justify-content: space-evenly;`

Comment: Good catch! However, that was not the problem (just copy-pasted from the wrong place...). I'll fix that to the code.

Ended up using divs to wrap the flex items and use margins to them. Still don't know what was the problem in the first place. Please educate me if you know!

Comment: At this point it's just a guessing game, Can you provide a working example ?