# create table dynamically, with 3 columns on each row

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app I want to make a "Cards" page, I want 3 cards on each row.

the relevant code looks like:

```
    static renderCards(cards) {
        return (
            <div>
                {cards.map((card, index) =>  
                    index % 3 == 0 ?
                        <div className="row" key={card.id}>
                            {MyComp.colData(card) }
                    </div> :
                         MyComp.colData(card) 
                )}

            </div>);
    }
```

where `MyComp.colData` returns a html of a single card

I tried to add the condition `index % 3 == 0` then add a row wrapper else return a column data.

but now it creates a single column on each row

Comment: I would suggest you use flex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24197376/7399478

Answer (score 0):

Creating A Row Then Appending 3 Columns in it. then Repeating the Same .

tell me if this what you want. i will explain more ....

```js
let section = document.getElementById("container")

let colCount = 3;
let rowCount = 3;
for (let i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
  section.innerHTML += `<div id="row${i}"></div>`;
  for (let j = 1; j <= colCount; j++) {
    document.getElementById(`row${i}`).innerHTML += `<div id="column">i am a column</div>`;
  }
}
```

```css
#row {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

#column {
  background-color: red;
}

#column:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: pink;
}

#column:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<section id="container"></section>
```